# Drupal 7 : Pass submitted value from webform to confirmation page and another webform

Tags: drupal, webforms, drupal-7, confirmation

In Drupal 7 I have two webforms.

When a user submits the first webform, I have the confirmation redirect. I would like to populate one of the fields in the **confirmation page** (and **second webform**) with one of the submitted values from the first form.

Then I will list the second webform in the same confirmation page (webform1)

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Stm.jpg)

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks

***I used this method to retrieve the value for confirmation page:***

[recupere the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mj8DE.jpg)

But I want to retrieve the value in the second webform

How can I do this?

And how can I list form results in confirmation page (form1)?

Comment: How do you get form results? Searched quickly, but didn't find anything useful...

Comment: Normally I use the views

Answer (score 0):

Here you have two option to do this.

1. Store the field value in $_SESSION and get that value.
2. Webform id is fixed, you can get result by using webform id with relevant userid and add to that result in

   hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)}{
    if($form_id == 'webform_client_form_YOURWEBFORMID'){

   }

using this you can able to get this value.